# WordPress database dump

Tags: wordpress

I have an offline WordPress installation I am using to explore WordPress and its tools, and have constructed a simple site.

This is off-line and not accessible from the internet.

I had dumped the database to an sql file from Mariadb using mysqldump and was surprised by the size (>400k) given the sparse content.

A lot of this seem to be webpages e.g. https://wptavern.com/wpml-website-hacked-customer-emails-compromised which seems to be a rant about a hacked site.

My question is Why is this in my database dump?
Where is it stored?

Comment: And you're already using `--skip-comments` and `--compact`, I trust?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a vunvebiliyty in the WPML plugin, do you have this installed.

You should also run Wordfence to detect any malware.